# While php operator with mysql Truncate not working

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, localhost

I have a bunch of websites stored as strings in 3 mysql tables. My script puts them into arrays, parse it, extracts all the links and sort them into 2 tables. Its broken in 3 identical modules which do the sorting.

The whole thing is looped with while to perform its operations every 30 seconds.

For some reason only the first time its working as intended, and nothing happens later.

Before I get to my code, I apologize for depreciated mysql, this script will be only to used on local machine and I will update it when the time is right.

Here is my code:

```
$i=1;

$domain1 = 'example1.com';
$domain2 = 'example2.com';
$domain3 = 'example3.com';

$robots1 = array("url1",
"url2",
"url3");


$robots2 = array("url1",
"url2",
"url3");


$robots3 = array("url1",
"url2",
"url3");

require_once 'Normalizer.php';

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost:3306','user', 'pass', true );
mysql_select_db( 't1000', $conn );

while ($i<=50000) {


$query = 'SELECT * FROM dump1';
$result1=mysql_query( $query, $conn );
$strings1=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
array_push($strings1, $row["link"]);
}
$query = 'TRUNCATE TABLE dump1';
$delete=mysql_query( $query, $conn );




$query = 'SELECT * FROM dump2';
$result1=mysql_query( $query, $conn );
$strings2=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
array_push($strings2, $row["link"]);
}
$query = 'TRUNCATE TABLE dump2';
$delete=mysql_query( $query, $conn );




$query = 'SELECT * FROM dump3';
$result1=mysql_query( $query, $conn );
$strings3=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
array_push($strings3, $row["link"]);
}
$query = 'TRUNCATE TABLE dump3';
$delete=mysql_query( $query, $conn );


// Module 1 start

$ii=0;
 $links = array();
 $edofollow = array();
 $enofollow = array();
 $internal = array();

foreach ($strings1 as $value)
{
$input=$strings1[$ii];
$htm=stripcslashes($input);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($htm);

  $arr = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a"); // DOMNodeList Object
  foreach($arr as $item) { // DOMElement Object
    $href =  $item->getAttribute("href");
    $rel =  $item->getAttribute("rel");
    $text = trim(preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", " ", $item->nodeValue));
    $links[] = array(
      'href' => $href,
      'rel' => $rel,
      'text' => $text
    );  
if (strpos($href, '://')!==false AND strpos($href, $domain1)==false AND  $rel!=='nofollow') 
    {
    $un = new URL\Normalizer();
    $un->setUrl( $href );
    $href= parse_url($un->normalize(), PHP_URL_HOST);   
    array_push($edofollow, $href);
}

else if (strpos($href, '://')!==false AND strpos($href, $domain1)==false AND $rel=='nofollow')

    {
    $un1 = new URL\Normalizer();
    $un1->setUrl( $href );  
    array_push($enofollow, $un1->normalize());  

}

else if (strpos($href,'://')==false or strpos($href,$domain1)!==false)

    { 
    $un2 = new URL\Normalizer();
    $un2->setUrl( $href );
        $href1=$un2->normalize();
    if (strpos($href1, 'TRANSCRIPTS')==false AND strpos($href1, '(')==false AND strpos($href1, ')')==false AND strpos($href1, '#')==false AND strpos($href1, 'javascript')==false AND  strpos($href1, '?')==false AND  strpos($href1, 'void')==false)       
    {
    if($href1=='' or $href1=='/')
    {}
    else{   

        if (strpos($href1, '://')==false)
        {$href1='http://'.$domain1.$href1;}


if (in_array($href1, $robots1)) { }
else {
array_push($internal, $href1);
}       
 }
  } 
 }
}  

$uedofollow = array_values(array_unique($edofollow));
foreach ($uedofollow as $value) {
$query=mysql_query("select * from dofollow where link='".$value."' ");
$duplicate=0;
if($query){
$duplicate=mysql_num_rows($query);
}
   if($duplicate==0)
    {
    $sql='INSERT INTO dofollow (link) VALUES ("'.$value.'")';
    mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    }
}

$uinternal = array_values(array_unique($internal));
foreach ($uinternal as $value2) {
    $query=mysql_query("select * from joblist1 where link='".$value2."' ");
if ($query) {
$duplicate=0;
$duplicate=mysql_num_rows($query);
   if($duplicate==0)
    {
    $sql='INSERT INTO joblist1 (link) VALUES ("'.$value2.'")';
    mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    }
}
}

$ii=$ii+1;
}

// Module 1 ends


// Module 2 start

 $links = array();
 $edofollow = array();
 $enofollow = array();
 $internal = array();

$ii=0;

foreach ($strings2 as $value)
{
$input=$strings2[$ii];
$htm=stripcslashes($input);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($htm);

  $arr = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a"); // DOMNodeList Object
  foreach($arr as $item) { // DOMElement Object
    $href =  $item->getAttribute("href");
    $rel =  $item->getAttribute("rel");
    $text = trim(preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", " ", $item->nodeValue));
    $links[] = array(
      'href' => $href,
      'rel' => $rel,
      'text' => $text
    );  
if (strpos($href, '://')!==false AND strpos($href, $domain2)==false AND  $rel!=='nofollow') 
    {
    $un = new URL\Normalizer();
    $un->setUrl( $href );
    $href= parse_url($un->normalize(), PHP_URL_HOST);   
    array_push($edofollow, $href);
}

else if (strpos($href, '://')!==false AND strpos($href, $domain2)==false AND $rel=='nofollow')

    {
    $un1 = new URL\Normalizer();
    $un1->setUrl( $href );  
    array_push($enofollow, $un1->normalize());  

}

else if (strpos($href,'://')==false or strpos($href,$domain2)!==false)

    { 
    $un2 = new URL\Normalizer();
    $un2->setUrl( $href );
        $href1=$un2->normalize();
    if (strpos($href1, 'TRANSCRIPTS')==false AND strpos($href1, '(')==false AND strpos($href1, ')')==false AND strpos($href1, '#')==false AND strpos($href1, 'javascript')==false AND  strpos($href1, '?')==false AND  strpos($href1, 'void')==false)       
    {
    if($href1=='' or $href1=='/')
    {}
    else{   

        if (strpos($href1, '://')==false)
        {$href1='http://'.$domain2.$href1;}


if (in_array($href1, $robots2)) { }
else {
array_push($internal, $href1);
}       
 }
  } 
 }
}  

$uedofollow = array_values(array_unique($edofollow));
foreach ($uedofollow as $value) {
$query=mysql_query("select * from dofollow where link='".$value."' ");
$duplicate=0;
if($query){
$duplicate=mysql_num_rows($query);
}
   if($duplicate==0)
    {
    $sql='INSERT INTO dofollow (link) VALUES ("'.$value.'")';
    mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    }
}

$uinternal = array_values(array_unique($internal));
foreach ($uinternal as $value2) {
    $query=mysql_query("select * from joblist2 where link='".$value2."' ");
if ($query) {
$duplicate=0;
$duplicate=mysql_num_rows($query);
   if($duplicate==0)
    {
    $sql='INSERT INTO joblist2 (link) VALUES ("'.$value2.'")';
    mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    }
}
}

$ii=$ii+1;
}

// Module 2 Ends


// Module 3 start

 $links = array();
 $edofollow = array();
 $enofollow = array();
 $internal = array();

$ii=0;

foreach ($strings3 as $value)
{
$input=$strings3[$ii];
$htm=stripcslashes($input);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($htm);

  $arr = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a"); // DOMNodeList Object
  foreach($arr as $item) { // DOMElement Object
    $href =  $item->getAttribute("href");
    $rel =  $item->getAttribute("rel");
    $text = trim(preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", " ", $item->nodeValue));
    $links[] = array(
      'href' => $href,
      'rel' => $rel,
      'text' => $text
    );  
if (strpos($href, '://')!==false AND strpos($href, $domain3)==false AND  $rel!=='nofollow') 
    {
    $un = new URL\Normalizer();
    $un->setUrl( $href );
    $href= parse_url($un->normalize(), PHP_URL_HOST);   
    array_push($edofollow, $href);
}

else if (strpos($href, '://')!==false AND strpos($href, $domain3)==false AND $rel=='nofollow')

    {
    $un1 = new URL\Normalizer();
    $un1->setUrl( $href );  
    array_push($enofollow, $un1->normalize());  

}

else if (strpos($href,'://')==false or strpos($href,$domain3)!==false)

    { 
    $un2 = new URL\Normalizer();
    $un2->setUrl( $href );
        $href1=$un2->normalize();
    if (strpos($href1, 'TRANSCRIPTS')==false AND strpos($href1, '(')==false AND strpos($href1, ')')==false AND strpos($href1, '#')==false AND strpos($href1, 'javascript')==false AND  strpos($href1, '?')==false AND  strpos($href1, 'void')==false)       
    {
    if($href1=='' or $href1=='/')
    {}
    else{   

        if (strpos($href1, '://')==false)
        {$href1='http://'.$domain3.$href1;}


if (in_array($href1, $robots3)) { }
else {
array_push($internal, $href1);
}       
 }
  } 
 }
}  

$uedofollow = array_values(array_unique($edofollow));
foreach ($uedofollow as $value) {
$query=mysql_query("select * from dofollow where link='".$value."' ");
$duplicate=0;
if($query){
$duplicate=mysql_num_rows($query);
}
   if($duplicate==0)
    {
    $sql='INSERT INTO dofollow (link) VALUES ("'.$value.'")';
    mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    }
}

$uinternal = array_values(array_unique($internal));
foreach ($uinternal as $value2) {
    $query=mysql_query("select * from joblist3 where link='".$value2."' ");
if ($query) {
$duplicate=0;
$duplicate=mysql_num_rows($query);
   if($duplicate==0)
    {
    $sql='INSERT INTO joblist3 (link) VALUES ("'.$value2.'")';
    mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    }
}
}

$ii=$ii+1;
}

// Module 3 ends

sleep(30);
$i=$i++;
}
```

I was trying to troubleshoot it for days now, mixed things around but no luck...

Comment: is your mysql user allowed to use the truncate command check your permissions?

Comment: yes, first time it empties tables as intended

Comment: script timing out ? checked apache/php error logs? could it be table names containing numbers don't know if mysql has issues with that may need to surround table names with ` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping it around in a do{} while();

ie:

```
$i = 1;
do {
    echo "some crap $i<br>\n";
} while($i<=50000);
```

Comment: Actually, this did the trick, speed was not to blame :) I didnt know you could twist the while operator in such fashion with 'do'. Thank you, Michael!

Comment: no worries man, yeah the while() and do ... while() is pretty nifty. the primary difference between the two of them is do-while checks the condition after the block is run, not before.